# Prove the rank of the matrix ${\bf B}=\left[ \left({{\bf HH}^H}\right) \left({{\bf HH}^H}\right)^+ - {\bf I} \right]$ is $\left( N-M \right)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we analytically prove the rank of the matrix ${\bf B}=\left[ \left({{\bf HH}^H}\right) \left({{\bf HH}^H}\right)^+ - {\bf I} \right]$ is $\left( N-M \right)$?

where the dimension of $\bf H$ is $N \times M$ ($N>M$), and the entries of ${\bf H}$ are randomly generated variables following the complex Gaussian distribution. $\left( \cdot \right)^+$ is the pseudo-inverse, and $\bf I$ is the identity matrix.

I found this result based on numerical examples, and therefore I'm thinking whether this can be analytically proven.

Some additional interesting observations via numerical examples: all the singular values of $\bf B$ are equal to 1;

Based on rank properties, I can prove that rank($\bf B$)$\le N-M$, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With probability $1$, $rank(H)=M$. Using the SVD, we may write (when $rank(H)=M$)

$H=U\Sigma V^*$ where $U,V$ are unitary and $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}diag(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_M)\\0_{N-M,M}\end{pmatrix}$where $\sigma_i>0$ is a singular value of $H$.

Then $HH^*=U\Sigma\Sigma^TU^*=Udiag(diag(\sigma_1^2,\cdots,\sigma_M^2),0_{N-M})U^*$, and, consequently

$(HH^*)^+=Udiag(diag(1/\sigma_1^2,\cdots,1/\sigma_M^2),0_{N-M})U^*$.

Finally $B=Udiag(I_m,0_{N-M})U^*-I_N=Udiag(0_M,-I_{N-M})U^*$ has rank $N-M$ as required (with probability $1$). Moreover, all the non-zero eigenvalues of $B$ are $-1$ (with probability $1$).

Comment: Thanks a lot loup blanc for your kind help!